# Getting data after page update using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I am wondering if anyone knows a way to get page data after it updates content from a post request via Selenium. I understand that the way Selenium works is by when you `get()` a website it parses the content at its current state and then that is what you have have to work with but I am wondering if anyone knows how to get this updated conent without "getting" the page again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wait for the ***visibility*** of some static element after the page is completely updated, before you attempt to get the data inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) as follows:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//xpath_of_static_element")))
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```